# How to set work_mem in hibernate configuration file

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I want to set *`work_mem`* (`set work_mem='100MB';`) for a single query in my hibernate mapping file. where do I need to set work_mem for the following query

```
<query name="queryname">
  <![CDATA[SELECT s from Stock A s where s.stockCode = :stockCode]]>
</query>
```

Comment: i am not sure : `<query name="anotherNOde"><![CDATA[set work_mem='100MB';]]></query>`

Comment: When i tried <query name="queryname"> <![CDATA[ set work_mem='100MB'; SELECT s from Stock A s where s.stockCode = :stockCode]]> </query> it is giving an exception like ERROR org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter:50 line 3:8: unexpected token: SET  line 3:8: unexpected token: SET and Error in named query: queryname org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: ';'

Comment: you just try to create a seperate node for `set work_mem='100MB';`

Answer (score 1):

You need to get access to your current Hibernate session and use doWork to execute a native SQL command:

```
session.doWork(new Work() {
                 @Override
                 public void execute(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
                       Statement s = null;
                       try {
                              s = conn.createStatement();
                              s.executeUpdate("SET work_mem TO '100MB';");
                       }
                       finally {
                              s.close();
                       }                                
                 }
          });
```

And then you can continue with your Hibernate query.